# How to dynamically allocate memory for an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, struct, contiguous

I am fairly new to C, and am having trouble figuring out how to allocate contiguous memory to an array of structs. In this assignment, we are given a shell of the code, and have to fill  in the rest. Thus, I cannot change the variable names or function prototypes. This is what has been given to me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct student {
    int id;
    int score;
};

struct student *allocate() {
    /* Allocate memory for ten students */
    /* return the pointer */
}

int main() {
    struct student *stud = allocate();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm just not sure how to go about doing what those comments say in the allocate function.

Comment: Get a better course. The function signatures are discouraged and are to be removed from a future standard. Use prototype-style, e.g. `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way to allocate and initialize the array is this:

```
struct student *allocate(void) {
    /* Allocate and initialize memory for ten students */
    return calloc(10, sizeof(struct student));
}
```

Notes:

- `calloc()`, unlike `malloc()` initializes the memory block to all bits zero. Hence the fields `id` and `score` of all elements in the array are initialized to `0`.
- It would be a good idea to pass the number of students as an argument to the function `allocate()`.
- It is considered good style to `free()` allocated memory when you no longer need it. Your instructor did not hint that you should call `free(stud);` before returning from `main()`: while not strictly necessary (all memory allocated by the program is reclaimed by the system when the program exits), it is a good habit to take and makes it easier to locate memory leaks in larger programs.

Comment: Use `calloc(10, sizeof(struct student))` to follow the style of the C spec for `void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);`

Comment: @chux: indeed! Answer updated. Too bad `calloc()` argument order is inconsistent with that of `fread()`, `fwite()`... but is consistent with that of `qsort()` and `bsearch()`...  I have never seen an architecture where the order matters, and I am curious what it would take.

Comment: @chqrlie Agree with your comments.  In a optimistic allocation system that allocates even without certainty, the system may use _size_ as a quanta  for future allocations, but I suspect things are fairly communicative.

Comment: that's pretty neat that `calloc()` sets all bits to zero. I didn't know that, and for learning something new, I'm thankful I was paying attention to this thread ;)